# Is there a way to use SAMPLE WEIGHT with XGBoost and DNN models in BigQuery ML?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, google-bigquery, xgboost

I have a dataset, where each instance has a different weight. In my case the weights differ up to orders of magnitude.
I want to train a Regressor type model that will consider these weights.
As part of my research, I've tried the following models: 'BOOSTED_TREE_CLASSIFIER', 'BOOSTED_TREE_REGRESSOR', 'DNN_CLASSIFIER', 'DNN_REGRESSOR'.
In the documentation ([XGB Models](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-boosted-tree), [DNN Models](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-dnn-models)) there seems to be no way to define a column for Weights.
(It is possible to define "class weights" for classifiers, which is a totally different thing).

As part of my research, instead of using weights I created an up-sampled dataset. However, this approach has two huge disadvantages:

1. It drastically increases the dataset size, which translates to costs of models training.
2. Due to significant differences of weights, I am forced to remove samples with low weights - to keep the up-sampled dataset of "reasonable sizes" (about 10-20 times larger than the original dataset). As a result an important piece of the signal is lost.

I see most of DNN and XGBoost libraries out there do support SAMPLE_WEIGHT parameter - both for Classification and Regressor model types ([here is an example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/457483/sample-weights-in-xgbclassifier)).

Is there a way to use SAMPLE WEIGHT with XGBoost and DNN models (Regressor/Classifier model types) in BigQuery ML?

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020-12-02, per-sample weights are not supported in BigQuery ML.

Comment: I just want to promote the OP a little bit.  There's a good example here https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_tweedie_regression_insurance_claims.html of why we need to have sample weights for regression (just GLM, never mind XGB and DNN).  BigQuery ML already supports class weights for classification, so sample weights for regression doesn't seem like much of a stretch.